# Passing JSON from Javascript Callback in JINT

Tags: c#, json, jint

I have a library which allows a developer to extend business rule triggers via JavaScript. Basically there is a function which allows the developer (in JavaScript) to subscribe to an event and pass a delegate as a "call me when this happens".

I am able to do this successfully, however am running into a snag when a function attempts to pass back a JSON or JavaScript object back to the C# layer.

Basically the code functions like this unit test:

```
Func<String, JsValue> callback = null;
Func<Func<String, JsValue>, object> registerCallback = (o) => callback = o;
Engine engine = new Engine()
    .SetValue("registerCallback", registerCallback)
    .Execute("registerCallback(function(parameter) { return { \"passed\": parameter }; });");
Assert.IsNotNull(callback);
var result = callback("test");
```

I would like it the C# variable "result" could have a JsValue or some other object which contains the data however the method throws the exception: Must implement IConvertable on the last line.

I can verify that "callback" is set to a delegate of appropriate type: Jint.Native.JsValue lambda_method(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure, System.String)}

And I don't have the issue if I pass back NULL. I'm sure there is some tiny (headbang once I figure it out) missing piece...

Answer (score 0):

Change `JsValue` to `System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject`. This will be the type of `result`, and it can also be safely cast to `IDictionary<string, object>`.

Answer (score 0):

Eugene's answer is correct. Not sure why it was downvoted.

Here is a working example:

```
Func<String, System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject> callback = null;
Func<Func<String, System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject>, object> registerCallback = (o) => callback = o;

Engine engine = new Engine()
    .SetValue("registerCallback", registerCallback)
    .Execute("registerCallback(function(parameter) { return { \"passed\": parameter }; });");
Assert.IsNotNull(callback);

IDictionary<string, object> result = callback("test");
Console.WriteLine(result["passed"]); // Will print "test"
```